# How can I distribute my Android App without deploying on GooglePlay Store

Tags: android

Actually I am ending my application but I don't want to put it into Google Play.
Are there any possibilities to prepare application for private usage with e.g. link or ref to friends who can install this?

Or the only one possibility is to run the Android Studio and apply application from this way (or of course Google Play)?

Comment: Apptoide, Amazon App store

Comment: You can deploy your .apk wherever you want, including some http server. To install it, the device should be developer enabled and unknown sources allowed.